# syntax of services

Tags: control, ros, syntax

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use rosservice for gazebo but i can't find the right syntax to use. where can i find the syntax i should use.

i was trying to use set_joint_properties on my little urdf i wrote and it wasn't working do to wrong syntax.
what i am realy trying do to is to symulate in gazebo a inverted pendelum and leave it up by using control methods. i am not sure how to start, it looks as if there is a control loop that is leeving it standing in place, otherwise it should have fallen over.
can some one give me an idea haw should i start.

the urdf model--

Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42816/syntax-of-services/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without more clarification on what you're trying to do (or what problems your encountered when you tried), all I can suggest is [this wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2